# Multiple pageviews from multiple trackers - GA and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have 2 trackers. `gtm1` and `checkout`

First tracker is called from GTM script ( www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX ) And I can't affect him.

```
ga('gtm1.send', 'pageview');
```

The other one is mine and I am calling it from my code.

```
ga('checkout.send', 'pageview');
```

On this way I have 2 pageviews and that's bad thing. 
Can I send another tracker to GA if other is already sent, but without do it as new pageview ?

PS: I don't have access to client GTM or GA account/settings

Comment: That's not a bad thing if the two trackers have different tracking ids. Use the Google Tag Assistant to check, but this seems to be intentional. If you want to send data to different accounts then two pageviews are how you would do it.

Comment: Google Tag assistant have ID that is connected with Google Analytics ID, So my two trackers have same ID. Only information's that they contain are different (about advanced e-commerce)

Comment: Okay, so this is bad. Of course you can simply remove the tracker in your page code altogether, or use it just for event tracking etc but not for pageviews (no good practice but entirely possible).